# JS: Nested promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I do not understand how to chain promises:

`getUser` is a promise function and also `search` is a promise function. `getUser` will return a language value.

With this data is not an array value, which should be returned by the `search` function

```
getUser(userId)
  .then(({ language }) => {
    const data = search('content', language)
    res.send(200, {
      content: data,
      user: { language }
    })
  })
  .catch((error) => next(error))
```

Comment: didn't you already ask this and get an answer? like an hour ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid nesting, you can use `Promise.all`: this will allow you to pass the `language` value through the chain as well:

```
getUser(userId)
    .then(({ language }) => 
        Promise.all([language, search('content', language)])
    ).then(([language, data]) => 
        res.send(200, {
            content: data,
            user: { language }
        })
    ).catch((error) => next(error))
```

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain what the problem is with this answer?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I am curious about why you're using `promise.all` here. Is language a promise? It looks like the return value from getUser. Why can't you just return `search()`'s promise?

Comment: When you return only the `search()` promise, then you will not have access to `language` when `res.send` is called (in the flat-chain model). NB: `Promise.all` can deal with non-promise values in the array. In that case it will treat those values as immediately resolved promises.

Comment: Of course. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see, why this answer was downvoted... Also do not understand why this question is downvoted that much...

Answer (score 0):

If `search` returns a promise, then you need to use `.then()` to get access to the data in that promise. And you should return promises in order to enable chaining at higher levels:

```
getUser(userId)
  .then(({ language }) => {
    return search('content', language)
      .then((data) => {
        res.send(200, {
        content: data,
        user: { language }
      });
  })
  .catch((error) => next(error))
```

Note that normally you could avoid nesting by returning the promise returned by `search()`, and chaining another `.then()` call afterward, but because you're trying to capture the language parameter from the original method call, you need the value to be in scope. Trincot's answer shows how you can capture the value of `language` for better chaining.